Creating a better navigation and filter for a festival or conference scheduler
I'm trying to figure out a good way to create a 6 level selector + filter on an app that shows me a schedule for a festival with artist slots and allows me to book artists to form my own schedule (or if it's used for a conference sessions/presentations for example)
This is how my app looks currently. Me and 1,000 other people that used it seemed to love it and find it easy to understand

The way I think about the hierarchy of data I want to select/filter on is:
Weeks (3 items): [All weeks]  [Week 1]  [Week 2]
Days (4 items): [All days]  [Friday]  [Saturday]  [Sunday]
Stages (15 items): [All stages]  [Mainstage]  [Freedom]  [...] [...]
Genres (40-50 items): [All genres]  [House]  [Trance]  [Drum'n'bass]  [...]  [...]
Artists (200 items): [All artists]  [Armin van Buuren]  [Martin Garrix]  [...]  [...]
Times: (10 items): [All times]  [14:00]  [15:00]  [16:00]  [...]  [...]
I don't want to clutter UI too much and show all 6 right away, so I was thinking of just showing first 3 as I already did with Weeks + Days + Stages, and maybe have a button at the top with the filter button that would expand it and add Genres, Artists, and Times. I'm also heavily aiming at mobile users, as I want it to be very mobile first, as people will use this during the festival and don't want it to be confusing or cluttered. For stages you either tap the arrows left and right or tap on the stage, that opens a simple modal with just a list of stages in rows that you can tap on and it selects it, since it's 15 items, I wanted to make it simple to select it in 2 taps and still see the whole list
Few ideas I had was to make everything into a dropdown and show the extra 3 dropdowns later on, but then it might be more cumbersome to have maybe checkboxes next to Stages in case I wanna select Mainstage and Freedom stage let's say. The other option I'm thinking is having some kind of a open dialog box, where the top could be a search input that filters down the list below, and have it like that for all the things that have more than 5 days to make it simpler for the user
Maybe the best would be to have both? So for example have "filter off" and "filter on" mode, which would be toggled by a button above, and the behavior would be:
Filter off - show only weeks + days + stages in the exact same way as we have today and without "All weeks", "All days" "All stages" option. This worked already well
Filter on - transform Weeks + Days + Stages into dropdowns, where you can select multiple options you want and add Genres + Artists + Times below it as 3 extra dropdowns
This feels a bit inconsistent for me tho, since in "Filter off" mode I will only show slots for Week 1 > Saturday > Mainstage for example, where as for "Filter on" I will show all the slots from all weeks, days, and stages, but maybe that's okay?
Please help me understand how to do this better and clearer for the user, so they can easily see their options and tap on it, and not do too much friction with tapping 4-5 times or something

Please add images of the design instead of a link. Also the question is too broad as it is. Can you try to focus on a single idea/problem/question and be more specific about it?

Added the image now instead of link
A specific question is - how would you show a filter in the 6 dimensions I mentioned alongside a simple view mode without a filter?

I think the description does not match the image.
As said in the question:

There are six filters
Each filter has n options

My logic is to select the filter and then browse the options for each one to see the results and click on them:

Edit after the comment
If there are 2 options selected that are outside of the screen, you can always use pills or chips at the bottom of the filter to show and/or clear them.

The image is what I have currently without filters, I don't have a better image because I don't know how to show it :D
I really love your idea, specifically about having 2 rows, 1 with all the filters, and the next with all the options you can scroll through, I think that really opens it up for possible select multiple options and such
With these designs I'm always concerned if: 1) users know they can scroll through (you show it well with arrows and circles), 2) if there are 2 options selected that are outside of the screen - how will they know
Huge improvement, thank you so much!

Answer updated.-
